# c# asp - UpdatePanel is causing a full page postback rather than just posting back itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a page with generated update panels like so:

```
foreach(DataRow r in GetSteps(ID).Rows)
    {

      UpdatePanel StepPanel = new UpdatePanel();
      StepPanel.ID = "stepPanel_" + r["StepID"].ToString();

      StepPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(GenerateInnerPanel(r));
      StepHolder.Controls.Add(StepPanel);         

    }
```

This generates all the UpdatePanels and adds the to a placeholder on my page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="StepHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Inside each UpdatePanel is a clickable panel which calls this javascript function:

```
function StepClick(sender, stepID){
  __doPostBack(sender.ID, stepID);
}
```

The javascript posts back and then I check the sender and add some details to the clicked update panel on page load.

The problem i'm having is that clicking on one of the divs in the update panel is causing a full postback rather than just posting back the contents of the containing update panel. Where do I set the update panels to only postback themselves rather than the full page? Maybe its not even a setting, in which case how would I do it?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set updatemode as conditional and set your divs as triggers or set ChildrenAsTriggers=true.

Also, ensure that you have scriptmanager placed in your ASPX page. You can call server side function asncronously by this way.

Comment: I've done as you said and set the updatemode to conditional and set the children as triggers.. No joy however :/ I've also added a script manager although i'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by it?

Comment: Scriptmanager is required for asynchronus operation of Updatepanel. Now, I dont think you need StepClick javascript side function. You can have similar function at serverside and bind to your step at client side. So whenever that function is called Updatepanel will initiate that call asynchronously.